Auto format text based on text style using react js
I need to format text based on provided text specific style using react js. e.g:
Here i have observed one thing like, if i pass text with some variable e.g:


const text = "\\nBubble\\nAir\\nSKY";
 <myComponent variableText={text} />



Then inside my component when i inspect the passed data it shows like below:
"Bubble
 Air
 SKY"

If i get data like in this type of format, It is working fine for me.
But when i direct pass the string text in my component like below:


<myComponent text="\nBubble\nAir\nSky" />



So after inspect in the component passed text it shows same like string.
e.g: "\nBubble\nAir\SKY";
How do we first get the string value as text in React js?
Need help

You might need to handle different cases using regular expressions and conditionally render the HTML. I would do it like following:


class FormattedText extends React.Component {
  formatText = (text) => {
    if (!text) return '';

    // Split the input text into lines
    const lines = text.trim().split('\n');

    // Define the variables to hold the output
    let result = [];
    let ulStack = [];
    let olStack = [];

    lines.forEach((line) => {
      if (line.startsWith('-')) {
        // Handle unordered lists
        const level = line.match(/-/g).length;
        const content = line.replace(/^-+/, '').trim();

        while (ulStack.length >= level) {
          result.push('</ul>');
          ulStack.pop();
        }

        if (ulStack.length < level) {
          result.push('<ul>');
          ulStack.push(level);
        }

        result.push(`<li>${content}</li>`);
      } else if (line.startsWith('#')) {
        // Handle ordered lists
        const level = line.match(/#/g).length;
        const content = line.replace(/^#+/, '').trim();

        while (olStack.length >= level) {
          result.push('</ol>');
          olStack.pop();
        }

        if (olStack.length < level) {
          result.push('<ol>');
          olStack.push(level);
        }

        result.push(`<li>${content}</li>`);
      } else {
        // Handle plain text with <br/> tags
        result.push(`${line}<br/>`);
      }
    });

    while (ulStack.length > 0) {
      result.push('</ul>');
      ulStack.pop();
    }

    while (olStack.length > 0) {
      result.push('</ol>');
      olStack.pop();
    }

    return result.join('');
  };

  render() {
    const { text } = this.props;
    return (
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.formatText(text) }} />
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const exampleText1 = '\nBubble\nAir\nSKY';
    const exampleText2 = '\n-Bubble\n-Air\n-SKY';
    const exampleText3 = '\n#Bubble\n#Air\n#SKY';
    const exampleText4 = '\n-Bubble\n--Air\n---SKY\n----Cloud';

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Example 1:</h2>
        <FormattedText text={exampleText1} />

        <h2>Example 2:</h2>
        <FormattedText text={exampleText2} />

        <h2>Example 3:</h2>
        <FormattedText text={exampleText3} />

        <h2>Example 4:</h2>
        <FormattedText text={exampleText4} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>



So, here FormattedText component uses dangerouslySetInnerHTML to display the HTML components.

I guess answer was OK, he did not reply anymore.
